# Prove that $X \succeq xx^T \iff \begin{bmatrix} X & x \\ x^T & 1\end{bmatrix} \succeq 0$

Tags: convex-optimization, matrix-equations, quadratic-programming, positive-semidefinite

I would like to prove the claim in the title:

$X \succeq xx^T \iff \begin{bmatrix} X & x \\ x^T & 1\end{bmatrix} \succeq 0$

The book I am reading ("Convex Optimization" by Stephen Boyd and Lieven Vandenberghe) states that this can be proven using Schur complement, but I can not figure out the proof by myself.

Comment: You can also show it in a very basic way by using the definition of semidefiniteness ($v^TMv\geq 0$) on both sides and comparing the things you get. Although maybe that will be repeating the proof of the Schur lemma.

Comment: Could you clarify how you would do this? Would you try to prove $X \succeq xx^T \iff v^T (X-xx^T) v \geq 0 \iff \begin{pmatrix} v^T &1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} X & x \\ x^T & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} v \\ 1\end{pmatrix} \geq 0$?

Comment: Could you please indicate on what page of Boyd and Vandenberghe's textbook this fact is stated?

Comment: @EvanAad unfortunately I haven't saved this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will write it here because the comments are too impractical. The big matrix is p.sd if and only if for any vector $y$ and scalar $c$ we have

$$\left(\begin{array}{c}y\\ c\end{array}\right)^T\left(\begin{array}{cc}X & x\\ x^T&  1\end{array}\right)^T\left(\begin{array}{c}y\\ c\end{array}\right)\geq 0.$$

This is equivalent to

$$\sum_{ij}X_{ij}y_iy_j+2c\sum_ix_iy_i+c^2\geq 0.$$

If you look at it as a quadratic function of $c$, it is always nonnegative iff its discriminant is nonpositive, that is

$$4((\sum_ix_iy_i)^2-\sum_{ij}X_{ij}y_iy_j)\leq 0$$

and that in turn is equivalent to

$$y^T(X-xx^T)y\geq 0.$$

Answer (score 2):

Let's prove it using the Schur complement, but in detail.

We compute
$$
\underbrace{\pmatrix{I&-x\\0&1}\pmatrix{X & x\\x^T & 1}}\pmatrix{I&-x\\0&1}^T =\\ 
\pmatrix{X - xx^T & 0\\x^T & 1} \pmatrix{I&0\\-x^T&1} = \\
\pmatrix{X - xx^T& 0\\0& 1}
$$
Thus, the matrix $\pmatrix{X & x\\x^T & 1}$ is positive semidefinite if and only if the matrix $\pmatrix{X - xx^T& 0\\0& 1}$ is positive semidefinite, which is true if and only if $X - xx^T \succeq 0$.

Comment: I noticed that you accepted and then unaccepted my answer.  Is there something that I can clarify here?

Comment: Do you use the fact that $\begin{pmatrix} X & x \\ x^T &1\end{pmatrix} \succeq 0 \iff \begin{pmatrix}I & -x \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} X & x \\ x^T &1\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}I & -x \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}^T \succeq 0$? Why is it true?

Comment: I will answer my question in the comment. Suppose $\begin{pmatrix} X& x \\ x^T &1\end{pmatrix} \succeq 0$. Then $v^T\begin{pmatrix} I& -x \\ 0 &1\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} X& x \\ x^T &1\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} I& 0 \\ -x^T &1\end{pmatrix}v = w^T \begin{pmatrix} X& x \\ x^T &1\end{pmatrix} w \geq 0$, here we defined $w = \begin{pmatrix} I& 0 \\ -x^T &1\end{pmatrix}v$.

Comment: @MindaugasK I was just in the process of typing that. Note also that the matrix
$$
\pmatrix{I & -x\\0 & 1}
$$
is invertible, which is important if we want the two statements to be equivalent.